# Ruby IF or Statement not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having trouble with a simple IF Statement. I have tried several thing win no success.

```
   <% if item.ITEM.strip != 'OEM-LABELS' || item.ITEM.strip != 'DISCOUNT' || item.ITEM.strip != 'OEM-DVR' %>

   <% if item.ITEM.strip != 'OEM-LABELS' or item.ITEM.strip != 'DISCOUNT' or item.ITEM.strip != 'OEM-DVR' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would simplify as follows

```
item = "A"
["C","B","A"].include?item #=> true
["C","B","D"].include?item #=> false


if ["C","B","D"].include?item
   do something
```

or

```
if !["C","B","D"].include?item  
   do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey So few things (without looking at more of your code)

1. Create a helper for this logic

   ```
   def needs_discounting(item)
     LOGIC HERE
   end
   ```

then in your view

```
  <% if needs_discounting(item.ITEM) %>
      STUFF
  <% end %>
```